# PHP & JSON: How can I get a value from where another value equals xyz?

Tags: php, json

I'm receiving a JSON and trying to interpret some values using PHP.

Example snippet from a JSON dump:

```
["11811"]=>
  object(stdClass)#15 (11) {
    ["parent_area"]=>
    NULL
    ["generation_high"]=>
    int(19)
    ["all_names"]=>
    object(stdClass)#16 (0) {
    }
    ["id"]=>
    int(11811)
    ["codes"]=>
    object(stdClass)#17 (3) {
      ["ons"]=>
      string(2) "08"
      ["gss"]=>
      string(9) "E15000008"
      ["unit_id"]=>
      string(5) "41421"
    }
    ["name"]=>
    string(10) "South East"
    ["country"]=>
    string(1) "E"
    ["type_name"]=>
    string(15) "European region"
    ["generation_low"]=>
    int(1)
    ["country_name"]=>
    string(7) "England"
    ["type"]=>
    string(3) "EUR"
  }
```

As there is lots of (nested) data, I need to obtain the value of ["name"] where ["type_name"] == 'European region'.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please show something that you have tried to do to accomplish this?

Comment: $response = file_get_contents($api);
 $jsonobj = json_decode($response);
 foreach($jsonobj as $json){
  var_dump($json);
 }

I only know how to go into each object $json->name etc.

Answer (score 0):

You could use **array_filter()**

```
$data_array = array(...);
function is_european($data) {
   return $data->type_name == 'European region';
}
$filtered = array_filter($data_array,'is_european');
```

And then use filtered array to obtain values.

Maybe a better way would be to use [JsonPath](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/), like this, assuming your array is a result of decoding JSON (object):

```
$names = jsonPath($data_object, "$.[?(@['type_name'] == 'European region')].name");
```

Haven't tried this myself, it may need a bit of correction.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
<?php
$json = JSON_decode(str,true);
$arr  = Array();
foreach($json as $f) {
 /* eg. $f = $json["11811"] */
 if($f['type_name'] == 'European region') {
  $arr[] = $f['name'];
 }
}
?>
```

Comment: Ummmm since when is `var` legal in PHP?

Comment: Thanks m93a. I managed to create the following from your example...

  $api = "http://mapit.mysociety.org/postcode/$postcode";
  $response = file_get_contents($api);
  $jsonobj = json_decode($response);
  foreach($jsonobj as $json){
   foreach($json as $obj){
    if($obj->type_name == 'European region'){
     return $obj->name;
    }
   }
  }